# What's wrong with my python code? I'm trying to make a generator code which replaces the string with the generator to give the final string

Tags: python

```
def make_converter(match, replacement):        
    d={match : replacement}         
    return d

def apply_converter(converter, string):    
    c1= "".join(str(x) for x in converter.keys())
    c2= "".join(str(x) for x in converter.values())
    print c1,c2
    c3=string.find(c1)
    if c3==-1:
        return string
    string=string.replace(c1,c2,1)
    apply_converter(converter,string)

# For example,

c1 = make_converter('aa', 'a')
print apply_converter(c1, 'aaaa')
#>>> a

c = make_converter('aba', 'b')
print apply_converter(c, 'aaaaaabaaaaa')
#>>> ab
```

Comment: Are you talking about Python generators? There aren't any in your code.

Comment: Aside: because of recursion limits, this code will break if there are lots of replacements -- and even if there were no recursion limits, it would loop forever if `match` were a substring of `replacement`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the result of the recursion. Your function returns the input `string` if no match is found, otherwise it returns nothing at all!

You want:

```
return apply_converter(converter, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from not returning the result, I have made some other cleanups:

```
def make_converter(match, replacement):        
    return (match, replacement)

def apply_converter(converter, string):    
    old, new = converter
    replaced = string.replace(old, new, 1)
    while replaced != string:
        string = replaced
        replaced = string.replace(old, new, 1)
    return string
```